# Read a dropbox csv file link from google colab

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a csv file stored on Dropbox in Google Colab.
I am using `pd.read_csv("dopbox_link")`, but getting the following error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3

How to resolve this error?

Is there any other way to read Dropbox files in Google Colab?

In the Dropbox link, I tried to change from `dl=0` to `dl=1`. But the error wasn't resolved.

Comment: I just checked, and replacing 0 to 1 at the end of dropbox link do the trick.